# getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders() is returning NULL

Tags: email2case

I tried to manually execute the following in Apex Anonymous and the result is returning NULL Case ID. Does anybody know how to use the new case header method?

```
List<Messaging.InboundEmail.Header> headers = new List<Messaging.InboundEmail.Header>();
Messaging.InboundEmail.Header messageHeader = new Messaging.InboundEmail.Header();
    
messageHeader.Name = 'Message-ID:';
messageHeader.value = '<BLAPR16MB37478D93BEC69718C9576BEBBF089@BLAPR16MB3747.namprd16.prod.outlook.com>';
headers.add(messageHeader);
 
 
Id caseId = Cases.getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders(headers);
 
System.Debug('JOSEPH DEBUG : caseId ' + caseId);
```

Result:

15:39:52.1 (7718512)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[11]|System.debug(ANY)
**15:39:52.1 (7727733)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|JOSEPH DEBUG : caseId null**
15:39:52.1 (7735978)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[11]|System.debug(ANY)

When I query for the EmailMessage record it is existing in the EmailMessage object.

```
SELECT Id, Headers, Subject, MessageIdentifier, ThreadIdentifier, ReplyToEmailMessageId, ParentId, ActivityId, ToAddress, FromAddress 
FROM EmailMessage 
WHERE MessageIdentifier = '<BLAPR16MB37478D93BEC69718C9576BEBBF089@BLAPR16MB3747.namprd16.prod.outlook.com>'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That method also needs a References header that is RFC2822 compliant. Meaning the message identifiers inside References header should be space delimited. The method is unforgiving on that header if it isn't RFC compliant. If the non-compliant references header reaches 780 characters, it will throw Unexpected Exception

Example:
header.Name = 'References';
header.Value = '<Message Identifier 1> <Message Identifier 2>';

Please check: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_Cases_getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders.htm

Also, no need to add colon on header.Name, just "Message-ID" will do.